# Vscode golang weird syntax highlight color

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, lint

I've recently set up a new go environment on my windows laptop. Upon writing a test connection on a test db, I noticed that the syntax highlighting is giving me these weird colors even though there's no error. "go run main.go" is also working fine and as intended. it's just that these red and grey syntax that don't sit well with me. anybody knows why? any help is appreciated. these colors have been driving me crazy.
[image]

Comment: It's unclear for me what is your question.

Comment: so from what I can see from other people's code snippets, the syntax highlight for struct name is not red. on top of that, the func ,type,package syntax are all greyed out. I was just wondering if I set up my go linter incorrectly.

Comment: There are not any linter highlights in your code screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that file extension is ".go" and if so, try another theme.